# what is wrong with DAX measure when trying to reference a calendar table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got a calendar table called "Date", which contains a distinct date for every day of the the past 3 years.

I also got a "Treatments" table, which contains a SessionID, Treatment Date and a Treatment Status, it looks something like this.

[image]

What I am trying to do, is add a new column in the Calendar table (This table is called Date) that counts the amount of "Completed" Treatments for each day for the past 30 days.

I've got the following DAX Measure

```
Completed Treatments = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Treatments),
    Treatments[Treatment Status] = "Completed",
    DATESBETWEEN(
        Treatments[Treatment Date],
        MAX(Date[Date]) - 30,
        MAX(Date[Date])))
```

but I keep getting an error of "The syntax for '[Date]' is incorrect.

Does anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Just add **'** for Date table.

```
Completed Treatments = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Treatments),
    Treatments[Treatment Status] = "Completed",
    DATESBETWEEN(
        Treatments[Treatment Date],
        MAX('Date'[Date]) - 30,
        MAX('Date'[Date])))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work for the dates? It is calculating a daily value per row, not a monthly value like I want it to.

Comment: Actually I do not know why, maybe this formula MAX is a baby formula hhhhhhh. For your next question, what do you mean by "monthly value"? Since the Calendar table is with "distinct date for every day of the the past 3 years" so do you want this monthly value in which date (for example the lastest date) or same value repeates in last 30 days? Or you want the table visual in dashboard show the monthly value? Explain in image would be great helpful for understanding.

Comment: Basically, I wanted to add a column on the calendar table (where each date is distinct) that gave you for every day the monthly count of Completed treatments for each day. I actually posted another question yesterday regarding this specifically and then managed to fix it with the EARLIEST function (The answer is on the other question I posted_